# Does Korean have a word for "偏爱" (love preference)?

Tags: sino-korean-words

"偏爱" means "a preference in love". A common usage is parents showing unequal love to one child over others.

Does Korean have a translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: 편애.

Found it after searching for translations of "favoritism" (a more accurate translation) instead of "preference", which is 선호.

Comment: Right, “편애 (偏愛).” It has the same characters and the same meaning.

Comment: @КонстантинВан Thank you! By chance, do you know any good Sino-Korean dictionaries? I feel it should be straightforward to look up such correspondences.

Comment: Sorry, just moved my comment to your answer. For Sino–Korean dictionaries, well, I use Naver [Korean](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%ED%8E%B8%EC%95%A0)/[Chinese](https://zh.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%E5%81%8F%E7%88%B1)/[Hanja](https://hanja.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%ED%8E%B8%EC%95%A0&range=all) dictionaries and [Wiktionary](https://zh.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%81%8F%E6%84%9B).

Comment: [zh.dict.naver.com](http://zh.dict.naver.com) seems to work great for this purpose, thanks!